# Where should I keep game level data?

Tags: android

I have game level data hardcoded in onCreate method of Activity Class, but b I want to access them from other classes to. The data itself doesn't change.
Where should I keep the data, what is the most efficient way?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)
    val words=arrayOf("aris","arsi","ris","risa","asi","sari")
    val wordstwo=arrayOf("mzeo","ezo","ezom","zemo","mze")//me
    val wordsthree=arrayOf("misni","is","minis","simi","mis","misi")
    val wordsfour=arrayOf("Tqveni","vqeniT","iqnevT","Tve","qve","vqeni")//"tqven"
    val challege:Array<Array<String>> = arrayOf(words,wordstwo,wordsthree,wordsfour)
    startGame(challege)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data that does not change I suggest you use a [`TypedArray`-Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray)

XML file saved at res/values/arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="words">
        <item>"aris"</item>
        <item>"arsi"/item>
        <item>"ris"</item>
        //... other items
    </string-array>
    //... other arrays
</resources>
```

Then in code:

```
val array: Array = resources.getStringArray(R.array.words)
```

This way you have a clean separation between code and data and can not accidentally change it.

Comment: What if I have over 100 pre-made game levels, will this method still be most effective?

Comment: The method will become more effective  the more levels you have, because you can only load the levels you need at a time.
 My guess is you are concerned that you will have to bring all data into this form, but that can be done with a small script you will have to write only once.

Comment: Also if you have someone (a non-coding person) creating levels for you it is ways to teach them how to create such config files. You do not want them to touch your code.

Comment: It's not a big game, it's just anagram game. Levels are anagrams of a single string.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static  class DataHandler that has the data and access it from this class in all activities.

Update(2022):
Don't use static classes :)
You can just use a file.

Comment: Creating a database for *static* content is overkill

Comment: @leonardkraemer the static class DataHandler isn't a good idea ?

Comment: It works, so it is not terrible. But keep in mind that if it is in a static class it will always consume the whole memory of the class. If it is in a configuration file you can load the party you need when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to save and change data in game play for your need (saving string array) is to use shared preferences:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: with the use of shared preferences will write and read the data every time that start or stop an activity. It will be better to do it with a class DataHandler (like i said in my answer)and access them every time he want ?

Comment: @Thelouras i did not vote your answer but shared preferences is faster and simpler than db

Comment: i change my answer. I proposed a static class DataHandler

Comment: @Thelouras in sharedPreferences data could be changed and saved between game starts and it is more flexible

Comment: as he said "The data itself doesn't change". So i believe a static class is better that  sharedPreferences